# How to print the few array values parallely

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class namefinder {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("                        NAME PREDICTER        ");

        System.out.println(" Row 1  A B C D E F");
        System.out.println(" Row 2  G H I J K L");
        System.out.println(" Row 3  M N O P Q R");
        System.out.println(" Row 4  S T U V W X");
        System.out.println(" Row 5  Y Z");
        System.out.println("enter the length of your first name in number!!! EX: vino , so length is 4");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int y =  scanner.nextInt();
        int s[] =  new int [20];

        for(int i=1;i<=y;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter whether the "+i+"letter of your name is in which row");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        s[i] =  scanner1.nextInt();
        }

      for(int i=0;i<=y;i++){

        switch (s[i]){

        case 1:
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
            System.out.println(""+'\t'+a[j]);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            char a[] = {'G','H','I','J','K','L'};
            System.out.println(""+'\t'+a[j]);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            char a[] = {'M','N','O','P','Q','R'};
            System.out.println(""+'\t'+a[j]);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            char a[] = {'S','T','U','V','W','X'};
            System.out.println(""+'\t'+a[j]);
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            for(j=0;j<6;j++){
            char a[] = {'Y','Z'};
            System.out.println(""+'\t'+a[j]);
            }
           break;

        }
        System.out.println("");


      }



    }


}
```

---

output:

```
                         NAME PREDICTER        
 Row 1  A B C D E F
 Row 2  G H I J K L
 Row 3  M N O P Q R
 Row 4  S T U V W X
 Row 5  Y Z
enter the length of your first name in number!!! EX: vino , so length is 4
3
Enter whether the 1letter of your name is in which row
4
Enter whether the 2letter of your name is in which row
2
Enter whether the 3letter of your name is in which row
3

S
T
U
V
W
X

G
H
I
J
K
L

M
N
O
P
Q
R
```

---

but i need to print as

```
S G M
T H N
U I O
V J P
W K Q
X L R
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You are doing it wrong. Do these steps.

1> Instead of creating a `char a[]` in each case, do this outside your `switch` block:

```
char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'};
char b[] = {'G','H','I','J','K','L'};
char c[] = {'M','N','O','P','Q','R'};
char d[] = {'S','T','U','V','W','X'};
char e[] = {'Y','Z'};
```

2>

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {  // Since 6 characters in an array.

    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {

        // Print first characters from each required array, then second characters on a new line, then third and so on.
        switch(sc[j] + 1) {  // Since counting starts from 0.

            case 1: System.out.print("\t"+a[i]); break;
            case 2: System.out.print("\t"+b[i]); break;
            case 3: System.out.print("\t"+c[i]); break
            case 4: System.out.print("\t"+d[i]); break
            case 5: System.out.print("\t"+e[i]); break; // Prone to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
    }
    System.out.println(); // Print a newline character after printing every line
}
```

3> Since `case 5` is prone to ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, put it in a try-catch statement. (Optional)

```
case 5:  try {

             System.out.print("\t"+e[i]);
         } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

             System.out.println("\t "); // Print an empty space with a \t character. 
         }

         break;
```

Comment: Array values are printed parallely as expected ,now i need to store each row values in a seperate array.could you pls help me on this . Thanks in advance,